# Labeling in TileMill with CartoCSS - Add line break between variables

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

I am labeling some points in TileMill using CartoCSS.

The labels are a composite of two variables

text-name: [NAME]+' '+[TYPE];

The rule above inserts a space between the two variables. How can I add a line break?

I have tried

```
text-name: [NAME]+<br>+[TYPE];
```

.

```
text-name: [NAME]+'<br>'+[TYPE];
```

.

```
text-name: [NAME]+'_'+[TYPE];
text-wrap-character: '_';
```

All to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for a new line in CartoCSS is `\n`. So you can do

```
text-name: [NAME]+'\n'+[TYPE];
```

The `text-wrap-character` approach will work as well, you just need to make sure to set `text-wrap-width` to a very low value such as `1` to trigger the wrapping.

Further reading: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-labels/